# A/B/C Testing - Aggregate data for comparison?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis

Let's say I have 3 ads: A, B and C.

These ads perform as follows-

```
Ad     Ad Impressions  Clicks     CTR*
A      2000            300        15%            
B      1000            50         5%
C      3000            300        10%

*CTR = click through rate = clicks/impressions
```

When assessing which creative is the most effective (that is to say, which yields the highest conversion rate) using hypothesis testing, is it ever reasonable that rather than comparing a single ad to another single ad (e.g. A vs B), that I could instead do A vs B+C, B vs A+C, C vs A+B?

As the impression volumes are not always equally distributed between A,B & C, it means that it would allow more of the tests (the above example is one of thousands) to be significant, however I'm concerned about the potential implications of this that I'm unaware of.

If there are problems with the approach, is there a clearly defined process for assessing testing in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is the question of interest: if your interest is in A vs B+C, you shouldn't even be defining B and C separately. But once defined, it is not legitimate to backtrack and "try" other combinations. Concerns will be a function of your particular approach to hypothesis testing (eg possible unequal variance for many parametric approaches). If, however, you are interested in post-hoc pair-wise comparisons, most post-hoc tests (eg Tukey) will give you all of the above combinations.